# Paste elements of a vector together with a given separator -R

Tags: r, string

I want to paste elements of a vector together, e.g

```
vec <- c("a","b","c")
```

to `string <- "a,b,c"`

I tried `paste0(vec, sep =",", collapse= "")`

but the output is `string <- "a,b,c,"`

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: See examples in `?paste0`

Comment: also `toString(vec)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use it like this:

```
paste0(vec, collapse=",")
```

the "collapse" argument specifies the value to use when collapsing the values into a single string